# Dependancies not met while instaling digikam 2.9

Tags: updates, package-management, digikam

I'm trying to install digikam 2.9 from

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip5/kubuntu-backports/ubuntu
```

Here is the message I got:

```
Les paquets suivants ont des dépendances non-satisfaites :

digikam: Depends: libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.7.0) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkfile4 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkhtml5 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkio5 (>= 4:4.7.0) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkipi9 (>= 4:4.8.80) mais la version 4:4.8.4d-precise~ppa1 va être installée
         Depends: libknotifyconfig4 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libkparts4 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libnepomuk4 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.2.0) mais la version 4:4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu1 va être installée
         Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libqt4-qt3support (>= 4:4.5.3) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) mais la version 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 va être installée
         Depends: libsolid4 (>= 4:4.7) mais la version 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1 va être installée
         Depends: digikam-data (= 4:2.9.0-precise~ppa1kde49) mais la version 4:2.9.0-precise~pp
```

I already tried running `sudo apt-get install -f` . This did not help, still get the same error message. Also tried the first answer but it doesn't fix the problem. I've done this, removed the packages detected, reboot. But still get exactly the same message about dependencies.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikevaughn/omnilinux
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try again .

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix the problem by:

Adding the PPA here

http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu

to my Software Sources then running an update which install the requested updated package.

And then the installation of `digikam 2.9` goes well.